# An investment and variance question for monthly payments

Tags: variance, finance

I have a question regarding a financial/statistical problem.

How do you calculate the variance of the outcome of an investment in a stock, when the investment is so called time diversified, i.e. spread out over time.

So, an investor invests an amount every month during 24 months in the same stock.
What is the variance of the outcome after 24 months (normal distribution assumed)? Expected yearly return 5%, annual std 10%.

I have spent a few hours googling but have not found anything (at least I could) translate into solving this.

Thanks in advance
Toby

Comment: Presumably the monthly investment is constant, right?  Would it be correct to interpret "outcome" as the value of the investment at the 24 month mark (rather than the sequence of 24 monthly returns)?  Are you assuming a normal distribution of monthly returns, of monthly relative returns, or of log monthly returns?

Comment: yes that would be correct, I am interested in the variance of the value at the 24 month mark. Normal distribution of monthly relative returns is assumed.
BR,
Toby

Comment: I've merged your two accounts, Toby. You'll need to [register](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) the one used in the OP.